# Como puedo imprimir texto con etiquetas en Angular?

Tags: html, json, angular, imprimir

estoy usando angular para imprimir datos recibidos de un Json, pero el Json trae texto con html y quiero que se pueda interpretar en angular, la forma en la que estoy imprimiendo los datos es asi: [image: quiero que el angular pueda interpretar las etiquetas y no que lo deje como texto]

Comment: Hola. Tienes una muestra de los datos que recibess?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias hermano, eres un crack funciono y sin nada de componentes y librerías! :D gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `[innerHTML]='tusDatos'` para obtener el resultado deseado.

Solo necesitas una etiqueta.

```
<div [innerHTML]='datos'></div>
```

Donde datos es una estructura `html` válida

```
datos = '<b>Esto es negritas</b><h1>Esto es un titulo</h1> '
```

Te dejo un ejemplo [funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nnveuw)

Comment: Es importante usar `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` del `DomSanitizer` de Angular para inyectar HTML de forma segura en los templates.

Comment: Hola, no es necesario. Checate esto https://angular.io/guide/security#angulars-cross-site-scripting-security-model